# Getting all the hyperlinks title in a webpage using a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on an application that needs to get all the URL title (one which we see when we hover the mouse on the hyperlink) present in the current tab. I am trying to make a chrome extension for the same. Find relevant files below:

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Sentiment Analyzer",
  "description": "This extension analyzes sentiments of tweets, facebook and instagram posts",
  "version": "1.0",
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon128.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "16": "icon16.png"
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon16.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "permissions": [
   "activeTab"
   ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sentiment Analyzer</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
        <button id="idanalyze"> Analyze </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

    document.getElementById('idanalyze').addEventListener('click', function(){
        temp = "";
        for(i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) 
        { 
            temp += " "+document.links[i].title;
        }
        alert(temp);

    }, false);

}, false);
```

When I tried the below code in console then it produced expected result i.e. gave title for each hyperlink but when I tried to get the same result using chrome extension it did not work. Any kind of help/suggestion will be appreciated.

```
temp = "";
        for(i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) 
        { 
            temp += " "+document.links[i].title;
        }
console.log(temp)
```

Comment: The popup is a separate page with its own chrome-extension:// URL, its own document, DOM, and even devtools. See [How to access the webpage DOM rather than the extension page DOM?](//stackoverflow.com/q/4532236)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only content script files are able to manipulate the page DOM, you are trying to access the site DOM from you popup page, so it won't work.

To solve it:
1. create a file and add it to your manifest.

```
   "content_scripts": [
   {
     "matches": [THE_URLS_YOU_WANT_TO_INJECT_FILE], //can be regex for any url
     "js": [YOUR_FILE]
   }
 ]
```

2. send message using from you popup file to the content script file using chrome.tab.sendMessage. the message will initialize the function that check the DOM.
3. listen to message using addEventListener. and run your function the manipulate the DOM.

this is a  high level explenation, every thing written in the documnation.

Content script - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

chrome tabs message - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs